# Autohotkey 5-Level cascading menu

Tags: script, macros, autohotkey, templates, dropdownlist

Can anybody who knows Autohotkey pls help me create a 5-level cascading menu (or at least tell me where can I find a ready-made template).

See sample screenshot (diagram):

[image]

The menu should work like these:

- UpArrow - move up (to select)
- DownArrow - move down (to select)
- RightArrow - reveal the next level menu (sliding menu)
- LeftArrow - go back (to where the cursor was)
- Enter - execute the corresponding action attached to that boxed-item

Every item on any level should be 'clickable' or 'enterable,' meaning, I could attach a macro to any item on any level, that when I hit 'enter,' it will execute that specific macro attached to that specific menu-item.

Additional info to make it clear:

The ones that we see in Word or Excel, that when you click FILE, a dropdown menu will appear, then select any item there, and another menu will appear (2nd level), choose an item there, another menu again (3rd-level), and so on.

Additional info again:

DavidPosti says that it's called a Cascading Menu. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidPostill : The ones that we see in Word or Excel, that when you click FILE, a dropdown listbox will appear, then select any item there, and another sublistbox will appear (2nd level), choose an item there, another sublistbox again (3rd-level, and so on.

Comment: So it's not a listbox it's a cascading menu?

Comment: @DavidPostill : Yes, thats right (cascading menu), but a bit different. Every menu should be able to hold a specific macro, meaning, I can hit enter and it will execute the macro attached to that item (even on the first, second, third or fourth level, not just on the final 5th-level). I already have my macros ready (57 simple macros). I just dont know how to make a cascading menu.

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but here goes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-create-cascading-menus-with-the-extendedsubcommandskey-registry-entry

Answer (score 0):

```
F1::
Menu, Main, Add
Menu, Main, deleteAll

Menu, Main, Add, Item 1, Item1

Menu, Item1, Add, Item1 Item1, Item1_Item1
Menu, Main, Add, Item1, :Item1

Menu, Item1_Item1, Add, Item1_Item1 Item1, Item1_Item1_Item1
Menu, Item1, Add, Item1_Item1, :Item1_Item1

Menu, Item1_Item1_Item1, Add, Item1_Item1_Item1 Item1, Item1_Item1_Item1_Item1
Menu, Item1_Item1, Add, Item1_Item1_Item1 , :Item1_Item1_Item1 

Menu, Item1_Item1_Item1_Item1, Add, Item1_Item1_Item1_Item1 Item1, Item1_Item1_Item1_Item1_Item1
Menu, Item1_Item1_Item1, Add, Item1_Item1_Item1_Item1 , :Item1_Item1_Item1_Item1 


Menu, Main, Add, Item 2, Item2

Menu, Item2, Add, Item2 Item1, Item2_Item1
Menu, Main, Add, Item2, :Item2

Menu, Item2_Item1, Add, Item2_Item1 Item1, Item2_Item1_Item1
Menu, Item2, Add, Item2_Item1, :Item2_Item1

Menu, Item2_Item1_Item1, Add, Item2_Item1_Item1 Item2, Item2_Item1_Item1_Item1
Menu, Item2_Item1, Add, Item2_Item1_Item1 , :Item2_Item1_Item1 

Menu, Item2_Item1_Item1_Item1, Add, Item2_Item1_Item1_Item1 Item2, Item2_Item1_Item1_Item1_Item1
Menu, Item2_Item1_Item1, Add, Item2_Item1_Item1_Item1 , :Item2_Item1_Item1_Item1 


Menu, Main, Show
return

Item1:
Item1_Item1:
Item1_Item1_Item1:
Item1_Item1_Item1_Item1:
Item1_Item1_Item1_Item1_Item1:

Item2:
Item2_Item1:
Item2_Item1_Item1:
Item2_Item1_Item1_Item1:
Item2_Item1_Item1_Item1_Item1:

MsgBox You selected`n`t"%A_ThisMenuItem%"`nfrom the menu`n`t"%A_ThisMenu%".
return
```

Comment: This looks great, Let me first inject all of my small macros later, and see if it will all work well. Thanks.

Comment: My problem is, I don't know how to start. I don't know where exactly to insert each macro :-(.. I'll try to figure it out later.

Comment: As you can see from this example, using the standard popup menus does not allow you to have a sub-menu where you can also select that item on the upper level menu, it will either be a selectable item or it will be a popup item

Comment: Furthermore, you cannot use the AutoHotkey `Enter::` hotkey when using the standard menu either, because the menu popup hijacks the thread and won't let anything else execute until it is dismissed

Comment: If you want to get exactly the functionality described in the original post, you could possibly look at a custom GUI, make it transparent, and use multiple ListView controls that get exposed or hidden.  It would take a lot of coding to do exactly what you're after, so the built-in menus might be better to start with if you can make them work